# Wordpress/Настройка темы/Обернуть блоки в группу

Tags: wordpress, wp-theme

Возможно простой и глупый вопрос, но чето я запарился с ним и хочется решить сразу, чтобы потом не возвращаться к этому.

Вкратце - осваиваю wp, столкнулся с проблемой непонимания как объединить блоки в Редактировании Страницы. Есть статья, состоящая из изображения, заголовка, текста и еще пары блоков. Это все добавлено сплошняком на страницу. Нужно создать ещё 1 такую же статью и хотелось бы структурировать контент на странице, поместив все блоки 1-й статьи в один блок или группу, чтобы иметь готовую структуру статьи и копипастить эти блоки статей, допустим.

Пробовал добавить блок "Группа", но не понял как вставить УЖЕ созданные блоки туда. Новые добавляются, а вот готовые не получается переместить.
Как это вообще реализовать, чтобы не удалять уже имеющиеся блоки, а тупо их обернуть в блок-контейнер?
Прилагаю скрин, ниже создал блок "группу", а выше - то, что нужно обернуть в эту самую группу. help someone)[image: скриншот]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я тут новичок, но где-то прочитал, что можно отвечать на собственные вопросы, если нашел ответ. Попробую) Может быть кому-то будет полезно.

Нашел решение. Не такое красивое, как хотелось бы конечно, но все же лучше, чем ничего.
Чтобы объединить несколько блоков статьи в один, нажал на пункт "Группировать" у одного из блоков, далее копировал все нужные элементы и добавлял их в эту "группу". Так обернул в группу все нужные блоки.

Чтобы можно было копипастить статьи по шаблону, нажал на группированном блоке на кнопку "Добавить в мои блоки", задал ему название "article". Усе.
Дальше чтобы повторно его использовать, просто добавлял новый блок и выбирал свой "article". А там уже можно менять пункты статьи, аля изображение, заголовок и т.п.
Главное только у блоков новых статей нажимать "Преобразовать в обычный блок", чтобы новая статья не привязывалась к нашему созданному шаблону "article" , иначе все статьи примут вид той, которую мы только что отредактировали, так как шаблон изменится.

Ну, как-то так) Всем спасибо за внимание! :D
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]